# Insert into certain part of database

Tags: c#, sql, database

Are there any Sqlite statements that allows you to insert data after a certain entry in a database? Example: I have 5 "John" entries and 3 "Jack" entries, I would like to insert another "John" into the database but it has to be inserted just after the last "John" that is alredy in the database.

Any ideas would be great. Thanx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't.

You can use a clustered index on the Name column to ensure that the new "John" is inserted next to the other "John", but it may be before, in the middle or after.

However clustered index is just a performance optimization to ensure good IO performance for certain queries. Databases does not guarantee that you get entries in the same order they are stored in the database.

I suspect that you want to display the entries after each other. This should be done by explicitly adding an `ORDER BY Name` clause to your SQL query.

If you really wan't to have the last "John" last when you query you should add either a sequence column, call it `ID`.

Then you can query

```
SELECT * FROM Persons ORDER BY Name, ID
```

of a date column, call it `AddedDate`

```
SELECT * FROM Persons ORDER BY Name, AddedDate
```

Comment: Thank you, I will be able to use this